# Weird Crosshair Gnome Desktop

Tags: debian, gnome

I am on Debian Buster amd64 with gnome-shell 3.30.1-2. I just did some updates and noticed that I now have this crosshair pattern on the desktop/background.
Does anyone know why this pattern, seen below, has appeared?

- Testing featured that was left enabled?
- New window organization hint?
- Weird plugin on my part?

Thanks!

[image: Gnome Desktop Crosshairs]

EDIT: Looks like the default background itself has a cross on it.
[image: Gnome Background Selector Previews]

Comment: Does the pattern survive when you change the background image?

Comment: No. The cross is gone if I change it to another background.

The background previewer seems to think that that particular (default) background has a cross on it.

Comment: If I reselect the default background, the cross still appears.
I checked out all the images in /usr/share/wallpapers . None of those SVGs show a cross in them using eog viewer.
Maybe a Gnome background SVG rendering error?

Comment: There's a similar cross near one of the corners of the lower left preview as well.

Comment: Compare this question that involves PNG and Windows: [Invisible PNG Image Layer that is only visible as a background](https://superuser.com/q/1224233/432690). Can something similar happen with SVG and Debian? It's worth investigating.